# iOS Two labels in one button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I want to make my own custom button with two Labels stacked vertically, like this: [image]

The top Label will be a FontAwesome icon using https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift

I am trying to do this like this:

```
// Initialize buttonLabel
var buttonLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
buttonLabel.text = "New Event"


//Change initial Label to FontAwesome Image
addEventButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(30)
addEventButton.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.CalendarO), forState: .Normal)
// Add label to button
addEventButton.addSubview(buttonLabel)
```

Which is called upon `viewDidLoad`

However, only the icon shows up. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an attributed string with a new line between the character and the string. NSFontAttributeName can be used to set a different font for a substring.

UIButton has a setAttributedTitle forState method.

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant Yes, it should. You can look at the [`NSAttributedString` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html) for more information.

Comment: I looked there, and I cannot figure out how to set FontAwesome as the font for the first part of the string

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant set this object UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(30) for key NSFontAttributeName in the attributed string.

Comment: I'm using Swift, and Xcode doesn't recognize NSFontAttributeName

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant It does: `NSMutableAttributedString(string: "test", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize()])`

Comment: Okay, got that, now how do I add a second line with different font to the string?

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant use the `- (void)addAttribute:(NSString *)name value:(id)value range:(NSRange)range;` method to apply attributes only to a certain range of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Another perhaps better alternative would be to save the images you need from FontAwesome. Include those images and set the button image accordingly. UIButtons already have the option for an image. Override `imageRectForContentRect` and `titleRectForContentRect` to position your views.

Using fonts you have to worry about the line heights, etc.
Further, giving your button a title that contains font awesome AND regular text will most certainly break accessibility, if you care about that. Try using voiceover with font awesome.

If you're set on using fonts, you should instead add a UILabel subview to the button and position your labels appropriately in `layoutSubviews`

Comment: One of the accessibility features in iOS - reads the UIControls to you. FontAwesome (and other icon fonts) will probably give you comical results. Obviously not your main user segment, but something to think about. 

I just listed it as one of the reasons to use an image for an icon, rather than a font.